# How many complex numbers $z=x+iy$ are there such that $x+y=1$ and $e^{i(x^2+y^2)}=1.$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am stuck on the following problem that says:

> How many complex numbers $z=x+iy$ are there such that $x+y=1$ and $e^{i(x^2+y^2)}=1.$ The options are as follows:
>   $1.0$
>   $2.$Non-zero but finitely many
>   $3.$Countably infinite
>   $4.$Uncountably infinite.

My Attempt:  From  $e^{i(x^2+y^2)}=1= e^{i(2n \pi)}$ which gives $x^2+y^2=2n \pi$ (where $n \in \mathbb N$) that indicates family of concentric circles with center at the origin. The required solution is the intersection of $x^2+y^2=2n \pi$ and the line $x+y=1$.But now I can not draw the conclusion.Am I going in the right direction? Can someone throw light on it.Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: That's a great start. You can take 4 out of the list.

Comment: You're doing very well... I think you *must* have found the intersection of these circles with the line. What is holding you up from finishing?

Comment: Like @rschwieb says, you're almost done. Substitute $y=1-x$ in the circle equations and solve the resulting quadratic equation in $x$. You'll find a neat parametrization of your solution set.

Comment: This is not about the complex number $z$ at all! It should be "How many points $(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$ are there..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x+y=1$ describes a line.
Any sufficiently big circle around the origin intersects this lline in two points. So we must have countably many solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but now consider how many times do the line and circles intersect.  Looks like it would be either option 3 or 4 though one is more likely if you consider the domain of n.  How many unique values of n exist?

Comment: I was trying to give a hint rather than finish the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir.I have got it. I guess option $3$ will be my friend.